# i have a question about the analogy between Hydraulic system and Electrical system

Tags: voltage, current, ac, dc, resistance

In Hydraulic system the Pump out oil "" flow "" , It doesn't out pressure , well what create the pressure is the " restriction " or "" orifice "" or "" resistance "" .

In Electrical system , The battery out "" flow of electrons "" , It doesn't out Pressure "" Voltage "" , Well what create the Voltage is the "" resistance "" or "" load "".

Now the question , is this analogy right ? , If it's right this mean that the restriction or resistance which create the "" pressure "" or "" voltage "" ?

Comment: A battery creates maximum voltage (zero current) without the presence of a load and, a hydraulic system creates maximum pressure (zero flow) when the pipe is fully blocked.

Comment: Some kinds of pumps create a certain pressure, and some kinds of pumps create a certain flow rate.

Comment: A pump would thus be a "current source" -- the "through" variable instead of the "across" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a personal preference, I would use air pressure and air flow and *not* use hydrology. There's a good reason. Electrons (the usual charge carrier in electronics) are more like a gas flowing in wires, than a liquid. So the macro-analogy stays closer to the micro-reality, IMHO.

Think about air tools, air compressors, and so on. The air pressure is like voltage here. Air volume is like charge and the rate of air volume is like current here.

Different air compressors have different air pressures they can support (rated in the US as PSI or "pounds per square inch") and you can often set the air pressure at some desired value, too.

The air compressor tank is like a capacitor. The volume of air stored in the tank, under some applied pressure at the moment, is like the amount charge that is stored on the capacitor under some applied voltage. You can use air, and as you do so the pressure in the tank will droop. Similarly, as you use current drawn from the capacitor, the voltage will droop too.

A competent air compressor will turn back on when the air pressure droops too much and will supply more air into the tank to maintain the specified pressure. Similarly, a voltage regulator will also provide additional charge to the capacitor to maintain the voltage on it as it supplies a circuit. Just as with the air compressor, where the air pressure varies a little (up and down) with use, so will the voltage at the output of a regulator vary a little (up and down) with use.

Air tools require different air flows to operate properly, specified in the US often as "CFM" or "cubic feet per minute." Some tools require only short pulses and some require continuous flow. Similarly, some circuits require only short pulses of current when they operate for a moment. And some circuits require a continuous draw, as well.

Air tools *also* require different air pressure values to operate properly, too. Just like different circuits require different operating voltages. Many tools sold in the US are rated for 90 PSI. But not all. And for some air tools, it's not the air pressure that matters quite so much, but the air flow (such as a tool used to inflate your car's tires, where a slow flow allows you to easily "top off" the tire correctly, regardless of the air pressure available -- so long as the air pressure available is more than the desired tire's pressure.)

How much air flow is required by a tool at their operating pressure depends upon the tool, itself, and not the air compressor. Much like circuits where the current required at their operating voltage depends upon the circuit and not the power supply. The air flow required for a air drill might be 4 CFM. But the air flow required for jack-hammer might be 140 CFM! The tool itself determines the valves, pipes, and mechanisms applied and these determine the air flow requirements for the job at hand. Similarly, circuits also include varying types of mechanisms inside; and these determine the current flow requirements needed to work correctly.

A power supply for a circuit merely needs to be specified to meet the voltage and current requirements, just like an air compressor for an air tool must be specified to meet the PSI and CFM requirements of some tool.

Many circuits can support some range of voltages (sometimes quite narrow, but sometimes fairly broad, too) and some range of currents (sometimes also narrow, but sometimes also broad.) A flashlight might be an example where it still can still be useful, even if the voltage and/or current diminishes over a range. A walkie-talkie might be an example where it works well only when the voltage supplied by its batteries are within a narrow range.

---

From the above, I think you can also see that you would need larger air hose diameters for a jack-hammer than for a nailer, in order to meet the much higher CFM required by the jack-hammer. (Similarly, you'd need larger wiring for circuits requiring more current.) You might meet the pressure requirements for that jack-hammer, with a tiny air hose. But as soon as you tried to use it you'd quickly find that the narrow hose *restricts* the ability of the air compressor to deliver the required air flow. Or, similarly, that even with the right size air hose to the jack-hammer you'd still have serious problems if you didn't have an air compressor that was *also* specified with a high enough CFM capacity for the jack-hammer. (The air compressor might support 90 PSI, but not support 140 CFM, for example.)

---

I much prefer the air compressor, air flow, air consumption model. Air is a gas. Electrons in conductors are a gas (to a first approximation.)

Comment: Air is compressible.  Charges really aren't.  A capacitor is not like a holding tank, but more like a spring-loaded hydraulic piston which needs to always have the same amount of fluid flowing out as flowing in.

Comment: It would be good to see the analogy for an inductor .

Comment: @Autistic Most just struggling to gather up a different viewpoint about voltage and current don't need to worry about that. And by the time they need to, they can drop the analogies. But, I suppose, an analogy would be a flywheel and enclosed fan coupled up and with an intake and outflow. The outflow would take time to allow airflow out, as the flywheel spins up, and might keep pulling air through pushing to outflow even when intake pressure is lost as it spins down. Some air tools are like that already and would have "inductance" of a sort, I suppose. Oh, well. That's off the cuff.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBJle0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But flow is not like Ohm's Law considering  dQ/dt=I and U=I*R  ( or V=IR)

Orifice Flow

- Pressure Drop across an Orifice \$∆P=\frac{GPM(Q)*Sg)^2}{29.81*d^2*∆P}\$
  for flow in GPM  ( U.S. system)
  This is because the flow is not linear in an orifice.
  [image]
- You can get a linear equation for  flow = area * velocity but is voltage area? not really